# Link in a circular image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In my webpage, I've an image, and a link in this image.

```
<a href='..'><img src='...' class='img-circle'></a>
```

(img-circle is part of the Twitter Bootstrap library)

I would like that the link is only on the image, e. g. on the circle, and not on the square. Do you know a solution please ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an anchor link on the image like so:

```
#a {
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:100px;
    background-color:#72CEE0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    left:150px;}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="a" onclick="window.location='http://whatever.com';"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
```

You will have to modify the `left`, `width`, `border-radius` and `height` properties above in order to match the size, shape and position of your circular image.

Here is an example from another answer on Stack Overflow:

http://jsfiddle.net/avTa8/

**EDIT:** It seems that Chrome may have a problem with onclick, although I am not sure what the real reason for this problem is, instead just simply place an `a href` around the `div` like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6UYTL/2/

Comment: @Arnaud check out the jsfiddle above, does that work for you?

Comment: Yes, but it is not exactly the same case.

Comment: This works for me and I'm using Chrome.. http://jsfiddle.net/6UYTL/ What version of Chrome are you using and what Operating System?

Comment: This JSFiddle example works for you ? For me, JSFiddle tries to go on Google.com (but doesn't succeed, maybe it is normal), if I click on the circle **or** in the square. I use Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m and Windows 7.

Comment: The clickable area in the jsFiddle is circular, you will need to change the properties to match the size, shape, radius etc of your circular image

Comment: For me, the clickable area is not circular, even in the jsFiddle.